# homogeneous matrix properties

Tags: matrices

If $\mathbf{g}\neq0$ is a non-trivial solution for equation $A\mathbf{g}=\mathbf{0}$ can there be a unique solution for non-homogeneous equation
$$A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$$

If we assume that $\mathbf{x}$ solves the second equation, by linearity $A(\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{g}+A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}$ (but this doesn't help me much). How should I tackle this problem? Geometrically?

Comment: Nope. If $Ax=b$, then also $A(x+g)=b$, so your solution is never unique.

Comment: Solution will be unique if and only if $A$ is regular.

Comment: What's the definition of regular matrix?

Comment: $A\in Mat _n(F)$ is regular if $\det(A)\neq 0$
A system of linear equations is exactly soluble if it consists of $n$ variables and $n$ equations. (in other words the system matrix $A$ has to be regular - composed of linearly independent row (column) vectors)

Comment: @Grostul I don't quite grasp how adding column vector of zeroes to our result $\mathbf{b}$ shows that $x$ is unique and not dependent on "free variables".

Comment: Ahhh...! So $\mathbf{g}$ is already a solution for the result for $\mathbf{0}$ and uniqueness allows you to have only one solution so $x$ has to be non-unique?

Comment: @ELEC This is what you wrote in your question: "if $g \neq 0$ is such that $Ag=0$, then...". So you have $A(x+g)= Ax+Ag=b+0=b$. Hence if $x$ is any solution of $Ax=b$, $x+g$ is another solution. Can you see now that the solution cannot be unique?

Comment: Damn. I'm stupid. I got mixed up. Makes perfect sense :) Thanks @Grostul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property
\begin{equation*}
A\mathbf{g}=0,\;\mathbf{g}\neq 0
\end{equation*}
shows that $A$ has a non-empty null-space and hence is not invertible. Let $P
$ be the projector upon this null space and $Q=1-P$. (Then $AQ\mathbf{f}=0$
implies that $Q\mathbf{f}=0$. )

In case $A$ is symmetric then $AP=PA$ and $AQ=QA$ so
\begin{equation*}
AQ\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}\Rightarrow \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
PAQ\mathbf{x}=P\mathbf{b}=0 \\
QAQ\mathbf{x}=Q\mathbf{b}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
Then we obtain a unique solution provided $P\mathbf{b}=0$.   If $A$ is not
symmetric then the null space of $A^{\dagger }$ also comes into play.